# Java indexOf not calling equals

Tags: java, overriding, equals, indexof

I want to understand why the overrides methods equals isn't called by the indexOf function. I have this class :

```
class Test {
    public Integer _test;

    public Test(Integer test) {
        _test= test;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(_test);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("equals function called");
        if (!(obj instanceof Integer)) return super.equals(obj);
        Integer test = (Integer) obj;
        return _test == test;
    }
}
```

And this is the code in my main :

```
List<Test> listTest = new Arraylist<Test>();

listTest.add(new Test(1));

System.out.println(listTest.indexOf(new Integer(1)));
```

Output : -1

---

Note that if I do this the function equals is called:

```
List<Test> listTest = new Arraylist<Test>();

listTest.add(new Test(1));

System.out.println(listTest.indexOf(new Test(1)));
```

Output : -1 equals function called

Comment: FYI, you're breaking `equals`'s contract, for example the part that says "It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got it the wrong way round.

[If you check the source code](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l295), `equals` is called on the argument of `indexOf`, not the elements. So, `Integer.equals` is being invoked, not `Test.equals`.

```
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                if (elementData[i]==null)
                    return i;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                    return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

That's `if (o.equals(elementData[i]))`, rather than `if (elementData[i].equals(o))`.

I suppose it's done this way round because `elementData[i]` might be null. Of course, you could add a null check:

```
               if (elementData[i] != null && elementData[i].equals(o))
```

but that's more verbose, and probably slower than doing it the other way round.

Answer (score 2):

You are searching for an `Integer` instance in a `List<Test>`, so you shouldn't expect it to find a match.

Yes, your `equals` implementation in the `Test` class may return `true` when you pass an `Integer` to it (which is a bad implementation), but the JDK probably uses `Integer`'s `equals` implementation to compare the `Integer` instance to the `Test` instances of your `List<Test>`, and therefore finds no match.